# OnStarting cannot be set because the response has already started. - SignInManager

Tags: asp.net-core, identity

I can't get past this error in my simple code. Why does SignInManager keep throwing error:
**OnStarting cannot be set because the response has already started.**
I am calling my _SignIn method from blazor Onclick Event

```
 public async Task _SignIn()
    {
        SignInByUsernamePasswordModel model = new();
        model.Username = this.Username;
        model.Password = this.Password;

        try
        {
            await signInComponent._SignInByUsernamePassword(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }       

 public async Task<SignInResult> _SignInByUsernamePassword(SignInByUsernamePasswordModel model)
        {

            string username = model.Username;
            string password = model.Password;

            SignInResult signInResult2 =  new SignInResult() ;

            try
            {
                SignInResult signInResult =  await _SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, false, false); ;
               
                return signInResult;
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
            *****Exception is thrown here!****
            }
            return signInResult2;
        }
```

Cookie Settings were previously giving me another error until I fixed this code, however, this can't be the culprit. I can't imagine at what point it is throwing error i.e at the time of creating a cookie?

```
builder.Services.AddAuthenticationCore().AddAuthentication()
.AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, options =>
{

    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

Comment: Can you share more about your startup.cs?

Comment: I've come accross the reasoning behind my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Researching Top errors in below Error Stack, led to the conclusion that the SigninManager would immediately start sending out the Response or reversing the Request flow to Response flow in  Request/Response Pipeline. The cause behind it is, Signin Manager makes use of **HTTPContext** to create cookies.

```
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.OnStarting(Func`2 callback, Object state)
```

This article describes https://startblazoring.com/Blog/SignInManager
that SigninManager cannot be used with Blazor directly.

Comment: "Article Not Found" :(

Comment: That was the best link I had. Was there a particular answer u were looking for? I can perhaps provide more insight

Comment: Thanks @N_E, I was experiencing the same issue as the OP, but I was able to get it resolved.